# Unable to get remote ip address in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i am getting link but how to use it.
http://nodejs.orgapitls.html#tls_class_tls_cleartextstream

Comment: What do you mean? and your link is wrong. its http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_cleartextstream

Comment: i am getting server undefined ...

Comment: i need to include any library for that ???

Answer (score 0):

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

```
var address = socket.handshake.address;

console.log("New connection from " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
```

}

check this too.. http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_socket_address